# How to check whether file was modified by third party application? I'm looking for tiny code example

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file

Using C# I can check whether file was modified by some program using sort of
`DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(filename);` I just store this time initially and compare it every several seconds with `timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;`

I want to know if there is another solution? Some kind of event handler, is it possible "to listen" to specified file and run some code accordingly in c#?

Comment: Please take a loot at [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) and see if that would help you.

Comment: Yes! It worked perfectly for my small task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) can raise events when changes to the file system are detected.

In your case it sounds like you'd want to subscribe to the `Changed` event, with a `NotifyFilter` of `LastWrite`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a File changed Event using File​System​Watcher.​Changed from System.IO to trigger any code on modify, so you don't have to poll it.

Answer (score 0):

The code below handles only changes in txt-files in a specified folder, but it is all I need. Compiled with csc.exe, this code works. Thanks guys for giving me a clue!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"C:\somePath"; // set correct path
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";  // watch for txt only
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        while(Console.ReadLine()==null); // wait for keypress
    }
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }
}
```